# Removing data (refreshing) WebGL Globe

Tags: javascript, webgl-globe

I'm playing with the WebGL Globe (http://globe.chromeexperiments.com/) and would like to be able to "refresh" it with new data and then animate it to the new state. The examples provided in the library don't help because they load data series at once when the page loads, but I'd like to load in new data dynamically (say, every 30 seconds)

Repeatedly executing the following with new `data` only updates the globe's data additively, so the bars "stack up" on the globe when new data comes in:

```
globe.addData(data, {format: 'magnitude'});
globe.createPoints();
globe.animate();
```

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to subtract / clear / reset the globe's data using the built in API (and then animate to a new state of data). Is this easily doable?

Comment: Isn't this exactly what they do on the page linked by you on line 144? Loading the data via ajax and tweening the bars to the new data.

Comment: Not exactly.. that example loads a data file "population909500.json" via ajax, but this data file has 3 datasets (one for each year) within it. Loading a new set of data and re-executing the call to globe.addData would cause the new data to stack on top of the old data

Comment: It looks like after  globe.createPoints() is called, no more Tweens can be made. This is a problem because I want to addData dynamically (I don't know what the new data is going to be).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. In your `globe.js` add the following lines:

```
function createPoints() {
    ...
    this.points.name = "lines"; // Add this line
    scene.add(this.points);
    }
}

// Create this function
function removeAllPoints() {
    scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName("lines"));
}

// Near the bottom of the code
this.addData = addData;
this.removeAllPoints = removeAllPoints; // Add this line
this.createPoints = createPoints;
this.renderer = renderer;
this.scene = scene;
```

Now you can simply do something like:

```
TWEEN.start();
globe.removeAllPoints();
globe.addData(data, {format: 'magnitude', name: 'results', animated: false});
globe.createPoints();
```

Comment: You are correct, but I thought I would mention that I had to add [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152132/three-js-collada-whats-the-proper-way-to-dispose-and-release-memory-garbag/33199591#33199591) to removeAllPoints() to prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 4):

The answer given by hobbes3 really helped. But just one small change.

You need not call `globe.animate()`.

I had used it in a project in which i update data every 5 seconds and calling `globe.animate()` over and over again brought rendering to a crawl.
Comment that out and you are gold.